# Redmine: can't get 2 instances running at the same time

Tags: apache, passenger, virtualhost, redmine, apache-config

I can't get 2 redmines to run at the same time in a Debian 7 server. Using Apache2 and Passenger (ruby rails)

The applications both work in test environment (Webrick server) and both work if I declare ONLY one virtual host in the apache config file. But if I declare both, this way, only the first one works:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName <myURL>/requests

  DocumentRoot /var/www/
  RailsEnv production   

  #PassengerRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby
  #PassengerLogLevel 4
  #RailsBaseURI /var/www/myapp/public

  Alias /requests /var/www/redmine_instance1/public

  <Location /requests>
    PassengerBaseURI /requests
    PassengerAppRoot /var/www/redmine_instance1
  </Location>

  <Directory /var/www/redmine_instance1/public>
    AllowOverride all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName <myURL>/project

  DocumentRoot /var/www/

  RailsEnv production   

  Alias /project /var/www/redmine_instance2/public

  <Location /project>
    PassengerBaseURI /project
    PassengerAppRoot /var/www/redmine_instance2
  </Location>

  <Directory /var/www/redmine_instance2/public>
    AllowOverride all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only have on virtual host responding on a specific port, your 2 instances both want port 80 thus this can not work.

One solution for you would be to have a reverse proxy on port 80 that redirects depending on the requested URL to one of the `apache` instances that would for example run on port 8080 and 8081 (defined as virtual hosts, don't forget to set the ports apache itself will listen on - usually configured in `ports.conf`).

Regarding reverse proxies there are different programs, `pound` is relatively easy to handle and configure.